# How to keep Flexbox enabled every time refresh page in Chrome devtools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome devtools has a great option to enable flexbox overlay so I can see the layout. But every time refreshing the page, all options always be reset. Is there anyway to keep Flexbox options enabled until I disable them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found your question while trying to find the answer to another question: How to remove this strange dashed border of a random color around some elements when the developer tools are opened? Never knew about this feature in chrome.

Answering your question, it looks like flexbox overlay is preserved for those elements which are included into the initial html. As soon as an element is removed (or not yet added while the page is loading), it disappears from the list and when it appear there again, the checkbox will be unset.

Answer (score -2):

Chrome devtools is a tool to manipulate the  DOM for experimenting without actually changing the source code. Because of that any changes will not be stored. So when you refresh the page the DOM will be build again from the source of the page. And with that also the flexbox options will be reset.